# How to set up the camera for a PS Vita game?

Tags: unity, camera

I am starting my first project for Unity and I want to start a new game for **PS Vita**. This console has a resolution of 960x544 pixels.

How do I have to set up my camera so that it adapts to this aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity Camera will always fit to the height , and it will scale its width towards left and right. You don't need to do anything to the camera to adapt it to 960x544. For testing purpose you can add a custom screen size to see how the actual game will look like. Go to Game window and select the drop down beneath to add a custom screen size.

Reference Image:-

[image: Screen Size]

Comment: What I meant to say was not "resolution" but "aspect ratio". The default camera has a different aspect ratio. I corrected the question.

Comment: The camera doesn't have an aspect ratio. If you change the screen size , then the camera automatically adapts to it. If you want to set up aspect ratio then click on "Fixed Resolution" drop down and you will find the aspect ratio option :)

Comment: Click "Fixed Ratio" dropdown? Where is that in the interface?

Comment: Sorry I mean "Fixed Resolution" . See the image which i have uploaded in the "Edit" box you see "Label" , "Type" . Look at the right side of "Type"